# Socket receive data only when reconnect network

Tags: java, android, sockets, socket.io, serversocket

I am facing a weird issue, I have written an app for Android by following  [Google Blog](https://code.google.com/p/boxeeremote/wiki/AndroidUDP).

Here is the code snippet:

Server:

```
 protected DatagramSocket createSocket() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
     if (mSocket == null) {
                DatagramChannel mChannel = DatagramChannel.open();
                mSocket = mChannel.socket();
                mSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
                mSocket.setBroadcast(true);
                mSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(PORT));
            }
     return mSocket; 
}
```

[Broadcasting Inside While loop Thread]

```
private void startBroadcast(String message) throws IOException {
    byte[] data = message.getBytes();

    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(
            data,
            data.length,
            mBroadcastAddress,
            mBroadcastPort
            );

    mSocket.send(packet);
}
```

Client:

```
protected DatagramSocket createSocket() throws IOException {
        if (mSocket == null) {
             DatagramChannel mChannel = DatagramChannel.open();
             mSocket = mChannel.socket();
             mSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
             mSocket.setSoTimeout(10000);
             mSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(PORT));
        }
        return mSocket;
    }

protected void receiveIntents() throws IOException {
        while (running) {
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(
                    new byte[MAXIMUM_PACKET_BYTES], MAXIMUM_PACKET_BYTES
            );

            mSocket.receive(packet);

            byte[] data = packet.getData();
            int length = packet.getLength();

            String msg = new String(data, 0, length);

            listener.onBroadCastResponseReceived(packet.getAddress(), msg);
        }
    }
```

I have debugged the code and found that the Server is working fine and broadcasting messages on time. But the Client is blocking on  "mSocket.receive(packet);". If I switch the WiFi connection On/Off it starts receiving message on the same socket instantly.